# SQL Query - put multiple condition on one product

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

Please help me with this:
I have a table like:

```
id_feature  id_product  id_feature_value
1              1           50
2              1           54
5              1           67
```

And I want to select from this table like this:

**select count(id_product) from `table` where (id_feature = 1 AND id_feature_value = 50) AND (id_feature = 2 AND id_feature_value = 54) AND (id_feature = 5 AND id_feature_value = 67)**

my query must meet the conditions. Like **having count(condition) = 3**

I don't know how to write this!

Please help me! and sorry my english!

```
    SELECT count( pf.id_product ) AS nr_product, value, fv.id_feature_value, filter
FROM `nk_category_features` cat_f
INNER JOIN `nk_feature_value` fv ON fv.id_feature = '11'
AND fv.value IS NOT NULL
INNER JOIN `nk_product_features` pf ON pf.id_feature = '11'
AND pf.id_feature_value = fv.id_feature_value
INNER JOIN `nk_product` p ON p.id_product = pf.id_product
AND p.product_active = '1'
INNER JOIN `nk_product_features` pf1 ON ( pf1.id_feature = '14'
AND (
pf1.id_feature_value = '21'
) )
WHERE cat_f.id_feature = '11'
AND filter >0
GROUP BY pf.id_feature, pf.id_product
ORDER BY abs( fv.value ) ASC
```

this is my query that i used now, but i don't like the solution width inner join, inner join on the same table

Comment: Please show an example of the output you are expecting, and the table structure (or at least the relevant field names), and we can provide a better response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
select id_product,count(*)
from table
where (id_feature = 1 AND id_feature_value = 50) 
   OR (id_feature = 2 AND id_feature_value = 54) 
   OR (id_feature = 5 AND id_feature_value = 67)
group by id_product
having count(*) = 3
```

To get just the total of products meeting the where clause

```
select count(*)
from 
  ( select id_product
    from table
    where (id_feature = 1 AND id_feature_value = 50) 
       OR (id_feature = 2 AND id_feature_value = 54) 
       OR (id_feature = 5 AND id_feature_value = 67)
    group by id_product
    having count(*) = 3
  ) tmp
```

Comment: You should get rid of the id_feature in the select_list / group by, otherwise this won't work correctly.

Comment: You meant OR (aa AND bb) ? UPDATE: now I see, it was in the OP, too.

Comment: And `group by id_product` only.

Comment: i want the count of the products theat meet the conditions

Comment: I have to display: feature_name(5 product) .... I the probelm appear when I have selected some feature

Comment: What conditions?   If you want the total only, see the second query I'll add to the example above.

Comment: It definitely should be OR, otherwise nothing will be selected